# canvas only mode in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

How do you toggle the 'canvas only' mode in inkscape? There seems to be a fullscreen(`F11`) mode but that doesn't get rid of all the buttons and only keep the drawing area. I don't know if this is a linux specific bug(since I use linux only), but I wanted to keep only the drawing area and get rid of all the buttons and tool areas temporarily(kind of like when you hit `Tab` in **krita.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>, for toggling toolbars, OR use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> for toggling toolbars & fullscreen at the same time.

**All shortcuts:** [Inkscape keyboard and mouse reference](https://inkscape.org/sk/doc/keys.html).